# Mocking readonly function nodejs

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, nestjs

I am trying to mock Web3.utils.fromWei fucntion but it is readonly and i couldn't manage to mock it.
i tried these but i got the same for both of them

```
jest
 .spyOn(mockWeb3.utils, 'fromWei')
 .mockImplementation((value, unit) => {
 return '10.9';
});
```

```
Object.defineProperty(mockWeb3.utils, 'fromWei', {
        value: jest.fn((value, unit) => {
          return 10.9;
        }),
      });
```

error is

```
TypeError: Cannot redefine property: fromWei
        at Function.defineProperty (<anonymous>)
```

fromWei function declared like is this

```
export declare const fromWei: (number: Numbers, unit: EtherUnits) => string;
```